# Run a target in a separate JVM

Tags: ant, exec

There is a interesting bug in the wsimport task that seems to destroy the content of a classloader as the task finishes. NetBeans likes to run ant scripts 'in process' and this bug raises all kinds of havoc after it runs a script that contains the task.

To work-around the havoc that results from the bug, I want to force ant to create a separate sub process for a secondary invocation of ant that would isolate the wsimport task in  its own private JVM.

It looks like the "ant" and "antcall" tasks keep the invocation of targets in the same JVM... though I may be wrong about that.

It seems like exec is clumsy for situations where the user might have multiple installs of ant, since the ant that the user is running might not be the executable that gets resolved when ant tries to find the executable="ant".

Is there a safe way to get the ant that is currently being used to be the ant that will be used to run a target in a different JVM?

Comment: Give exec a absolute path, and put this path in a properties file for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the value of the `ant.home` property.

```
<project default="test">
    <target name="test">
        <echoproperties>
            <propertyset>
                <propertyref prefix="ant."/>
            </propertyset>
        </echoproperties>
        <echo>Ant Home: ${ant.home}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```